# Orbeon: add section for each row in repeating grid

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

I would like to build a form that has some kind of overview at the top, where the user defines a list of items (repeating grid). For each item, there should then be a section further below (repeating section) where the user needs to add additional information to that specific item (it's A LOT of information, that's why I need a whole section per item and can't just add additional fields in my repeating grid).

So the easiest way would be to let the user manually add a section per item, but that's not very user friendly and also I need to make sure that there is exactly 1 section for every item.

I tried using `count($my-item)`, `count($my-grid)` and `count(xxf:repeat-items($my-grid))` as the min and max iteration count of my repeating section, but neither work. Also when I add `$my-item` as the calculated value of the first text field, always the first item in my grid is taken (should be the i-th, i being current iteration count).

Demo here (should be self-explanatory):
http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/92384bdcfd5dfeef2f79e79540e566501e6e5243

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Very clear, and it's possible to do with custom XForms code but not with the UI. It's not exactly trivial to write such code, unfortunately.

Comment: @ebruchez thanks, that's unfortunate :( And how about just making the repeating section have exactly as many iterations as the repeated grid, is this also not trivial :/? (And potentially populating a dropdown with the values in the grid?)

Comment: @ebruchez sorry for asking again, but could you answer my to comment above real quick? I'm really stuck trying to find a solution for my usecase...

Comment: Sorry about the delay. It's some work to come up with that code. We'd definitely like a good solution. Let me try in the next few days but no promise yet!

Comment: No worries, thanks a lot for taking the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orbeon Forms 2018.2 will have a component to automatically synchronized repeated content. See the [documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/services-and-actions/synchronize-repeated-content) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much Erik! I was not yet able to test it, but I will let you know as soon as I get to it.

Comment: Works like a charm! Very much appreciate it!